# Magento 2 : block function call from another block function

Tags: php, magento2

If I want to call any function from a block file in another block file, then how that is possible?

~Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if you need to call a function declared in another block file you have to extend the block

```
class YourBlockClass extends OtherBlock
```

But if you need to call the function without extending the block you have to put the function in a helper that is made to have functions that are called in many places.

Comment: but there for block class, there is a need to extend the /View/Element/Template class if the __construct is used. so how to fix that?